# Start Android need some guide lines

Tags: java, android, database, wcf, business-intelligence

I am here to ask for your help i am software developer i have been developing business applications for a while now in several technologies such as ASP.NET, Silverlight ,WPF, WCF services, SQL basicly Microsoft technologies this is my background, i have recently started to get into Android\Java, what i am looking for is some guide lines (best practices) on where to invest my time so i can learn as fast as possible and use most of the knowledge that i already have since i am working in this after my working hours and the time ain't much :(

My goal is to develop Business Applications and Games in Android that said:

- **Server communication**

  1. Can i take advantage of WCF Services knowledge i
     have and use them? Whats the alternatives?
  2. SOAP or REST?
  3. JSON or XML?
  4. Security SSL? I cant afford certificates whats the best alternative?
     Is the encryption enough?
- **Data Storage**

  1. Database Engine recommended?
  2. Files -> Encryption?
- **Development**

  1. I have been using the Android SDK (ADT Bundle) comes with eclipse as IDE recommendations?

Other suggestions are more them welcome :D

Thanks a lot for your time and sorry for the long post

Comment: This is a very generic question, which is likely not to be answered - see [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) for more information. If you want to increase the odds of getting responses, try to be more specific in what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read about SQLite for databases, its similar to the sql databases you must have used.
The ADT bundle is good.

Read Android Developers Guide : http://developer.android.com

This should be a good point to start.